# Is this protest sign referring to Europe?

Tags: quotes, sexual-abuse, law-enforcement, immigration, germany

[image: Description below]

Is the above picture, of a woman holding a sign with the text

> You can get raped but not protest against rape
>
> # World's largest democracy

referring to Europe?

Example tweets: [1](https://twitter.com/Temidor/status/691430389961887744) (containing a hashtag about sexual assault by refugees in Germany), [2](https://twitter.com/michalrygiel/status/686314012708061184) (doesn't contain the image, but does use the quote, explicitly about Germany) [3](https://twitter.com/RNRPennsylvania/status/685959293724680192) (contains the image, doesn't mention Germany but the replies do)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It may appear as if it's about police failing to stop the 2016 [New Year's Eve sexual assaults in Germany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Year%27s_Eve_sexual_assaults_in_Germany), but using [water cannon and tear gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Year%27s_Eve_sexual_assaults_in_Germany#Local_population) on [Pegida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pegida) demonstrations.

But the picture pre-dated the assaults in Germany, and was about double standards in India (which is sometimes referred to as the world's largest democracy). [Example reference](http://usoftoday.tumblr.com/post/112967157128/you-can-get-raped-but-not-protest-against-rape), which was posted on March 7, 2015:

> “You can get raped but not protest against rape.
>
> #WORLD’S LARGEST DEMOCRACY"
>
> - Following the Delhi Gang Rape
>
> December 27, 2012
>
> India Gate, New Delhi, India